# Unable to delete some entries

Tags: entries, entry, entry-type

It is weird that I can delete some entires in the app but some I can't. When selecting specific entry to delete, I don't see the option to delete it. I only have "edit entry" and "view entry". In some other entries I have the "delete..." option as well.
Why is that?

Comment: Are entries you can delete channels or structures? And ones you can only view or edit Singles? You can't delete Singles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define different permissions in Craft CMS, if you are not admin its likely someone restricts your access.

Furthermore you can't delete entries in a section of type single - those entries will always exist

Comment: Yeah, those entries are in the single section. So there is not way to delete them, no?

Comment: You can delete the section but not the entry unless you work with your DB or PHP